# How to make a correct Oauth2 request in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, clio-api

I'm using Ruby on Rails for get a token using Oauth2 for [Clio](https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation#section/Authorization-with-OAuth-2.0) app. So, I install the following gem:

```
gem 'oauth2'
```

And this is my code:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_KEY_CLIO, CLIENT_SECRET_CLIO, site: SITE)
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, :redirect_uri => 'http://127.0.0.1/approval')
return token
```

Where the variable `code` is send by frontend. And is a code that the clio app send when user make a login in his clio account.
But the redirect_uri URL did not exist. However, I created it and the only thing it does is get the code parameter and return it.

Still, it does not work. According to the documentation I can put the default URL that is `https://app.clio.com/oauth/approval` but it does not work either. I always have this error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "The provided access grant is invalid, expired, or revoked (e.g. invalid assertion, expired authorization token, bad end-user password credentials, or mismatching authorization code and redirection URI)."
}
```

I remember that this error happened before. But it was solved when the redirect_uri value was changed.

What is wrong with the redirect_uri? Could someone provide me with an example of Oauth2 requests?

Answer (score 0):

seems like it should work readin other threads. Add port to your calback url like or what port your app is running
http://127.0.0.1:3000/approval

Comment: And that static IP, could be a simple URL that do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

In `redirect_uri` I needed the URL that generate `code` variable. So, if `http://127.0.0.1/approval` exists and is accessible by internet but not generate the code so, it's not working. But if I put the correct url that generate code, all it's works.

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_KEY_CLIO, CLIENT_SECRET_CLIO, site: SITE)
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, :redirect_uri => 'http://address_generate_code_from_frontend')
return token
```

Comment: Where does 'code' come from?